# BoxConstraints Error when stretching a row widget

Tags: flutter

I have a `Card` widget in a `ListView` widget and the card has the following code structure to it:

```
return Card(
      child: Row(
        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/my-img.jpg'),
            width: 150,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // THIS HAS NO EFFECT
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(content.title),
                    Text(content.description),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(Icons.accessibility),
                        Text('cool')
                      ],
                    ),
                    Text('something else'),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

I'm trying to make the `column` in the `row` have a `spaceBetween` alignment since right now it the `column` is vertically centered. I tried adding a `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to the `Row` widget, but I get an error:

> BoxConstraints forces an infinite height

Answer (score 0):

`Column`s take all the available height. Consider wrapping the `Column` inside `Expanded` with a `Container` of fixed height.

To make a `Column` take as much space as possible, set `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`. However all the widgets are packed up and all `Alignments` will have no effect.

So probably what you are looking for is to set the `height` of the `Row` with the the maximum height of its `children` `widget`s. This can be achieved by wrapping the `Row` with `IntrinsicHeight`.

```
Card(
  child: IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Row(
      // ...
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I want the height to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You could add a SizedBox between the Column and Row.

```
Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(content.title),
                    Text(content.description),
                  ],
                ),
                //Sized Box
                SizedBox(height: //whatever double),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(Icons.accessibility),
                        Text('cool')
                      ],
                    ),
                    Text('something else'),
                  ],
                )
```